# Define constant in a different namespace php

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

Here's what I was doing in the past

```
//file: bar.php
defined('MYC') or define('MYC', 'val1');
//file: bootstrap.php
define('MYC', 'val2');
```

I would include bootstrap.php first which would set `MYC = 'val2'`.
Now bar.php is in the \Foo\Bar namespace, i.e. to say

```
//file: bar.php
namespace Foo\Bar;
defined('MYC') or define('MYC', 'val1');
//file: bootstrap.php
//following doesn't work
//const \Foo\Bar\MYC = 'val2';
//?? what do I do here ??
```

Comment: You code should still work regardless of namespace because define() function defines global constants, they are visible in any namespace.

Comment: thanks, I got that by experimenting, and I also figured I can't do conditional `const MYC = 'val1';` in `namespace Foo\Bar;` so I guess I will have to live with shitty_long_namespaced_global_constant_names :(

Comment: define() isn't namespace aware.  You'd have to do `define (__NAMESPACE__ . '\CONST_IN_NAME_SPACE')` to get it to create a constant in the current namespace.  Alternatively, you can use `const` if you don't have to calculate the value of the constant before defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `define` the key to have the namespace in the name.

Comment: do these constants defined by `define()` always land up in global namespace ? it looks like so, let me dig in and report back

Comment: looks like, `define('MYC1', 'val1')` in any namespace is MYC1 constant, where as `const MYC2` in `namespace Foo\Bar` is actually `\Foo\Bar\MYC2` , and there is no way I can do `const \Foo\Bar\MYC2` outside `\Foo\Bar`, so all that jazz about constants within their own namespace is NOT going to work for me :(